# Load settings view from code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm working on an extension and I'm checking to see if settings have values, if not, I want to show an error and provide a button that launches the settings editor so the user can add those settings.

I think my path forward is to use `executeCommand` and provide a built in command that does this for me, but I've been having trouble finding a list of built-in available commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hidden in the [key-bindings section of the documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/customization/keybindings#_preferences), I found the command I was looking for - `workbench.action.openGlobalSettings`

The full solution looks like

```
commands.executeCommand('workbench.action.openGlobalSettings');
```